# How to find records based on timestamp

Tags: csv, timestamp, filemaker

I m trying to import a CSV file on which there is a field `created date` which is in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format. I'm trying to find records based on **timestamps**.

**Example:**

I want to find records which are created between `2013-12-06 {14..17}:00` but it's not working.

Comment: If the FileMaker field is set as a timestamp field and not a text field you should be able to use "completeStartTimestamp...completeEndTimestamp" as the search query (with three dots between the two timestamps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Variable [$StartTime;"2013-12-06-14:00"]
Set Variable [$EndTime;"2013-12-06-17:00"]

## ----- use Omit to find your records

## --- 1st omit while CreationTimpeStamp > $EndTme.   -> it will keep only the records with creationTimeStamp Less than 2013-12-06-17:00.

## ---- 2nd Omit while CreationTimpeStamp < StartDate ->it will keep only the records with creationTimeStamp more than 2013-12-06-14:00

now you have the find set which you want.